# correct output for enum intilization

Tags: c#, .net, enums

i declare enum

```
enum Month
    {
        January , February , March , April , May , June , July , 
        Augest , September , Octobre , November , December 
    }
```

then in the main prog

```
static void DoWork()
    {
        // to do
        Month first = Month.January;
        Console.WriteLine("First Month of the Year : {0}", first);
        first++;
        Console.WriteLine((int)first);

    }
```

the output on the seond line should 2

but what i get actually is 1

what is the problem is that ( pass by value issue or somthing else )

Comment: Try your `Console.WriteLine((int)first)` line before `first++`, you'll understand why you get that value.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the first item in an enum is '0', with each item incrementing by `1`. You can assign values manually, however, and that should fix the issue for you.

Note that, in your case, just setting the first item to `1` should do the trick, but you can specify a value for any and all of them:

```
enum Month
{
    January = 1, February , March , April , May , June , July , 
    Augest , September , Octobre , November , December 
}
```